# I want to search in the map using the item in the list

Tags: c++

Now I have a map, which is the command_map. And I have a list, called address_list. In the command_map, each pair is address and command. In the address_list, each item is address.

So what I want to do is search for the address stored in the address_list in the command_map. And when it's found, print out that command and its address. Otherwise, simply print out that command.

I was using nested for loop to do this. But it doesn't work.

```
for (list<string>::iterator it_address= address_list.begin(); it_address != address_list.end(); ++it_address)
{
    for (map<string,string>::iterator it=command_map.begin(); it!=command_map.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it_address == it->first)
        {
            cout<<"Addr_"<<it->first<<":"<<endl;
            cout<<"         "<<it->second<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"         "<<it->second<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What!? Use [map find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).

Comment: I tried that but I am not sure if I did it correctly. Can you show me how to do it or give any hints?

Comment: Bud just use Google to find examples of how to use `map::find`.

Answer (score 1):

Dont search the map yourself, use the find method. It is a Red-Black Tree so searching it the way you are doing will be costly. Use [std::map::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).

```
for (list<string>::iterator it_address= address_list.begin(); it_address != address_list.end(); ++it_address) {

    auto myCommand = command_map.find(*it_address);

    if (myCommand != command_map.end()) {
        cout<<"Addr_"<<myCommand->first<<":"<<endl;
        cout<<"         "<<myCommand->second<<endl;
    } else {
        cout<<"         "<< *it_address <<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I tried your way but this will only print out the command that are found. It seems it will never get into the else case.

Comment: @Frank, It will go into the else, anytime the address is not a key in the my_command map.